# SWF content shrinks in chrome

Tags: html, css, flash, scale

I have a button made in flash which is saved to an SWF file with the size 146W 69H. I have doubled checked in flash and this is actual size. However when I get the file on browser it gets shrunk down to 53W and 14H.

Currently I have it in an unordered list as a many, but if I move it outside of the ul, it remains shrunken. I tried setting scaling on the object param without varied result but none that makes the text it's actual size.

HTML main:

```
$sublinks = "<li><object width='130px' height='100px' data='pics/links/news.swf'></object></li>";
```

HTML included design:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        $titleP - 3cstudios
    </title>
    <link $cssed rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='left'>
            <ul class='subLinks'>
                $sublinks
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="top">
```

and CSS:

```
.left{
margin-left:25px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:20px;
width:175px;
height:1873px;
background-image:url('../pics/leftMenue.png');
float:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat}
.subLinks{
margin-top:180px;
margin-left:11px;
background-color: red; //used it to check corect size of area.
height:1600px;
width: 113px;}
```

Comment: http://www.verypdf.com/flash-to-image/swf-to-png-converter.html I just found this, have not tried it.

Comment: Well, I don't want it as a pdaf image cause then I don't get the different effects I do with my swf.